# For named vectors and matrices, does [[ ever use partial matching without passing the exact=FALSE argument?

Tags: r, subset, names

I've recently read [this section of the R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing) and become very confused. It says:

> For vectors and matrices the `[[` forms are rarely used, although they have some slight semantic differences from the `[` form (e.g. it drops any names or dimnames attribute, and that partial matching is used for character indices).

Am I misreading it? It seems to say that `[[` allows partial matching (presumably by default) for named vectors and matrices. However, I know this to be obviously false:

```
> lett<-setNames(sample(26),paste0(letters,letters,letters))
> lett[["aaa"]]#No partial match
[1] 23
> lett[["a"]]#Error
Error in lett[["a"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

so what did the language definition mean? It could be talking about the `exact=FALSE` flag that you can set, but this seems a very strange way to do that. In fact, [a later section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors) makes the following claim, which my above code disproves, so I'm even more confused:

> For `[[` and `$` partial matching is used if exact matching fails, so `x$aa` will match `x$aabb` if `x` does not contain a component named "aa" and "aabb" is the only name which has prefix "aa". For `[[`, partial matching can be controlled via the exact argument which defaults to `NA` indicating that partial matching is allowed, but should result in a warning when it occurs.

Is the language definition simply out of date?

Comment: The default Usage is `x[[i, exact = TRUE]]`.  So, you may need to change the `exact = FALSE` to return the value `lett[['a', exact = FALSE]]#
[1] 25`

Comment: @akrun See my latest edit. I fully believe you, but the language definition seems to disagree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think the language definition is - at least partially - indeed out of date. The help page of `help("[[")` regarding the `exact` argument states

> Controls possible partial matching of [[ when extracting by a character vector [...]. **The default is no partial matching**. Value NA allows partial matching but issues a warning when it occurs. Value FALSE allows partial matching without any warning.

Usage supports this claim:

```
x[[i, exact = TRUE]]
x[[i, j, ..., exact = TRUE]]
```

The following code proves these defaults, as well.

```
set.seed(1)
lsub <- letters[1:3]
lett <- setNames(lapply(sample(3), c), paste0(lsub, lsub, lsub))
lett
#> $aaa
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $bbb
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $ccc
#> [1] 2

# partial matching
lett$a
#> [1] 1
lett[["aa", exact = FALSE]]
#> [1] 1

# no partial matching
lett[["aa"]]
#> NULL

# partial matching with warning
lett[["aa", exact = NA]]
#> Warning in lett[["aa", exact = NA]]: partial match of 'aa' to 'aaa'
#> [1] 1
```